# Need to Add / Subtract Group totals for Income Statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have designed an Income Statement in SSRS.  It has two row groups, the account type and the account from the chart of accounts makes up the detail.  The problem I have is that I need to add and subtract some of the group totals.

For example, there is a group of accounts names Sales, the next group is Returns and Allowances, the next group is COGS.  I need to to insert a row that sums the Sales and Returns and Allowances groups.  Then I need to insert a row after the COGS group that subtracts the COGS to total from Sales and Returns and Allowances totals.

For example:

```
Sales
  Acct 1
  Acct 2
Sales Total

Returns and Allowances
  Acct 3
  Acct 4
Returns and Allowances Total

Net Sales = Sales Total + Returns and Allowances Total

COGS
  Acct 5
  Acct 6
COGS Total

Gross Revenue = Net Sales - COGS  (or Sales Total + Returns and Allowances Total - COGS Total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding what your data looks like it's difficult to give an exact answer but I would make life easier by adding an extra group to your dataset. You could easily do this in the dataset query.

I created some sample data with an additional outer grouping column. I also added a sort column just for simplicity but you could sort that out however suit you best.

Here's the sample data script.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(OuterGroup varchar(20), AmountType varchar(20), Account varchar(20), Amount decimal(10,4), SortOrder int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('Net Sales', 'Sales', 'Account 1', 10.1, 1),
('Net Sales', 'Sales', 'Account 2', 15.5, 2),
('Net Sales', 'Returns & Allowances', 'Account 3', 2.6, 3),
('Net Sales', 'Returns & Allowances', 'Account 4', 3.7, 4),
('COGS', 'COGS', 'Account 5', 1.1, 5),
('COGS', 'COGS', 'Account 6', 1.2, 6)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I used this directly in the dataset query. As you can see the 'outer gorup' will allow us to group on this in the report.

The report design was a simple table with totals added to each of the three groups. The groups were on OuterGroup, AmountType and then the default details group. I added a total to each of these.

Here's the design

[image]

Other than adding a bit of test to the total caption expressions the only thing I edited was the final Gross Rev. expression

The expression is

```
=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value * IIF(Fields!AmountType.Value="COGS", -1, 1))
```

All we are actually doing here is summing **all** the amounts but multiplying the COGS amounts by `-1` first to make them negative.

This gives the following results

[image]

You could then Delete the first column (but not the group!) if you moved the gross rev. caption to the next column obviously...